# How to insert data by a partial view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I want to insert data using partial view for this action method which I have mentioned below.

The problem is that when I submit the Form it doesn't gave me any response.

What can I do with that post the comments and redirect to this page when comment is post?

And my partial view is located in a shared folder.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Comments([Bind(Include = "CommentId,UserComments,UserId")] Comment comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(comment, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.UserAccounts, "UserId", "FirstName", comment.UserId);
        return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Rendering partial view in layout.

```
 @Html.Partial("_Comments", new OnlineTaxiReservationSystem.Models.Comment())
```

and the partial view is here:

```
  @model OnlineTaxiReservationSystem.Models.Comment

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Comments", "Home")',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: {
            //put the data that you want to save from the partial here
            UserId: $('#userId').val(),
            UserComments: $('#content').val()
        },
        success: function (_result) {
            window.location.href = "Home/Index";
        }
    });
});
```

```
  @if (Session["user"] != null)
     {
   using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Your Feedback</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 9%">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "User Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @*@Html.Label(Session["UserName"].ToString(), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label label-primary col-md-1" })*@
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.Editor("UserId", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "userId" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserComments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.UserComments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "content"} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserComments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  }

  <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>
  }
```

Comment: While debugging in your browser: Open the network tab, and post the relevant call to the method please.

Comment: remove the type=submit from the input as it will post the form immediately, but you handle the click from a js-script.

Comment: and use #btnSubmit as its a ID not a class

Comment: still not working @Mithgroth

Comment: @Farman Actually my post wasn't suggesting a solution, I'm asking for more information about your problem. What happens in Developer Tools -> Network tab when you try to submit the form, can you please provide that information?

Comment: sorry, now it giving the error 404 i mean the partial view is not found in shared folder

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. Just get rid of that pointless script, and change the view to use `@using (Html.BeginForm("Comments", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { ... }` and in the POST method , redirect to the `Index` method using `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making a call to the wrong URL:

You need to add `e.preventDefault();` if you are not going to submit by button but from javascript instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function () {
    e.preventDefault(); //cancel the default behavior
    //do this instead (the ajax call):
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Comments", "Home")',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: {
            //put the data that you want to save from the partial here
            UserId: $('#userId').val(),
            UserComments: $('#content').val()
        },
        success: function (_result) {
            window.location.href = "Home/Index";
        }
    });
});
```

If you can provide the full details of your 404 call, I can be more spesific.

Comment: Thanks for the response.                                                                                                               
 The partial view 'Comments' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Comments.aspx
~/Views/Home/Comments.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Comments.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Comments.ascx
~/Views/Home/Comments.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Comments.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Comments.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Comments.vbhtml ....this is the exact error now

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/H2i3x3k.jpg
Check other tabs, make sure you are sending the right parameters, put a breakpoint to your action in the controller and see if it hits, enable all exceptions in Exception Settings. 500 just means "can't do this because an error happened", dig deeper please. Either you are sending wrong parameters, or having an exception in the action method and not catching it since you got it disabled in the Exception Settings.

Comment: @Farman What is the path to your Partial View? If it's not under `Home` or  `Shared`, you need to spesify its path like: `@Html.Partial("~/MyPath/_Comments", new OnlineTaxiReservationSystem.Models.Comment())` Can you see the partial view getting rendered?

Comment: my partial view is present in shared folder and the action method is present in home controller

Comment: Well, somehow it is not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188896/how-to-insert-data-by-a-partial-view-in-mvc/48189385?noredirect=1#comment83358243_48188896